# Failed to configure a DataSource on Tomcate

Tags: java, database, tomcat, datasource

I'm trying to deploy my application on Tomcat server locally and i'm getting an error for ( Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded data source could be configured. ) but I don't have any Database configured in my application.

I have removed all dependencies related to data source but it didn't worked.

My POM file :

```
   <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



</dependencies>




<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>/sample/servlet/container/deploy/directory</webappDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**UPDATE**

below is application properties file ( i have removed all values to post it here  )  :

```
server.port=
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client.client-id=
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.client.client-secret=
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.client.issuer-uri=
```

Please check below error : 
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpQXx.jpg)

Comment: Hint: Check your `application.properties`

Comment: @fabfas I didn't configure any data source in  application.properties file , that's why i'm confused !

Comment: Can you share stacktraces from the errors?

Comment: @fabfas please check my update

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue using two different approaches:

**1. Defining the data source**

- Define the data source in the `application.properties`
- Add datasource dependency in your `pom.xml`

**2. Disabling the auto-configuration of the data source**

Disable the auto-configuration using the spring.autoconfigure.exclude property in `application.properties`:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: Note: A click on "accept" next to this answer, optionally together with an upvote, is stackoverflow's built-in way to say "Thanks it works !!" ;)